# ul on 1 line different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

I've got some problems with alignment of the `ul`-tag. When it is in a low resolution like for example 320x480 the text isn't on one line.

I have tried changing my font size from `pt` to `em` but it still doesn't work.

This is my code I used to get where I was:

HTML:

```
<div id="location">
    <ul id="spacing">
        <li id="B"> <a href="HomePage.html">B</a> </li>
        <li id="R"> <a href="HomePage.html">R</a> </li>
        <li id="E"> <a href="HomePage.html">E</a> </li>
        <li id="C"> <a href="HomePage.html">C</a> </li>
        <li id="H"> <a href="HomePage.html">H</a> </li>
        <li id="T"> <a href="HomePage.html">T</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 320px)
{
    #B:hover,#R:hover,#E:Hover,#C:Hover,#H:Hover,#T:Hover
    {
        font-size: 25pt;
        transition: 0.5s;
        right: 20px;
        margin-right: 5%;

    }

    #B,#R,#E,#C,#H,#T
    {
        font-size: 20pt;
        padding-left: 10%;

    }
}
```

I know this will probably be an easy fix, but I really don't see it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to recreate this problem in a JSFiddle? It looks fine to me when I do it (Opera).

Answer (score 1):

`li` by default are block elements. They occupy one line each.

```
#B,#R,#E,#C,#H,#T
{
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

This part of your code should probably contain something like a `float:left` or `display:inline` to put the `li`'s in one line.

I'm guessing you have another media query that aligns those `li`'s in a single line on large resolutions.

Comment: That I didn't think of that!